# Making CXF web service calls from within the same JVM

Tags: java, cxf

I have a web service running (let's call it the integrator)

I would like to make calls using the client library from the same JVM. The reason for this is that there's a client which creates a serialized file (object stream) of objects which are for the client library generated from the wsdl.

Is there a way to use the client library in the same JVM as the server, and program it so that it doesn't go over HTTP?

The original problem is that the client will initially replicate a ton of data to the service making millions of calls which is too slow. so the original solution was to generate the serialized file of all the objects for the client calls and create an importer on the same machine of the server. This worked great to speed things up, but still get errors even on the local machine (read timeouts, etc which messes things up). I'm hoping to import the serialized data directly into the server, but the objects are all for the client library not the native server classes.

Comment: Well if you don't need web service calls, refactor the application and call the Java class directly?

Comment: yeah, that's obvious. Except there's a huge cost there, which is why i was looking at this as an interim solution.